Very ample sheaf contains global section missing points.
Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, exercise 16.2.J :
Let $X$ be a projective $k$-scheme, $L$ is an ample invertible sheaf, and $M$ is any invertible sheaf. Let $q_1, ..., q_m$ be points of $X$ (not necessarily closed). Show that for sufficiently large $n$, there is a global section of $L^{\otimes n} \otimes M$ that does not vanish at any $q_i$.
Hint : If $q_1$ is not in the closure of any $q_i$, find a section of $L^{\otimes n} \otimes M$ vanishing at all the $q_i$ for $i \neq 1$, but not vanishing at $q_1$.
It also says to use the property that for any coherent sheaf $F$, for sufficiently large $n$, $L^{\otimes n} \otimes F$ is globally generated.
I tried using the hint and induction on the number of points. Suppose it's true for $m-1$ points. Let $s_i$ vanish at $q_j$ for all $j \neq 1, j \neq i$. Then, their tensor product vanishes at all $q_i , i \neq 1$, but does not vanish at $q_1$. But their tensor product is not a global section of $L^{\otimes n} \otimes M$, but rather, it's a global section of $L^{\otimes mn} \otimes M^{\otimes m}$.
I then tried adding the $s_i$. I get a section that doesn't vanish at any $q_i$. This is what I originally wanted to prove, but it doesn't help me prove the induction hypothesis.
How can I prove the statement in the hint?

Could you link the version of the notes you're using? I couldn't find this exercise in the ones I have.

@Daniel https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGsep0824public.pdf  - I always use the latest one. I'm on the September 8, 2024 one.

To prove the hint, let $I$ be the ideal sheaf of $\overline{\{q_2\}} \cup \cdots \cup \overline{\{q_2\}}$ and use that $L^n \otimes M \otimes I$ is generated by global sections to find one which doesn't vanish at $q_1$.
For $n >> 0$, there is then a section $s \in \Gamma(X, L^n \otimes M)$ which vanishes at $q_2, \dots, q_m$ but not at $q_1$. By the induction hypothesis, there is also a section $t \in \Gamma(X, L^n \otimes M)$ which doesn't vanish at any of the $q_2, \dots, q_m$. Consider the subspace $$W 
 := \langle s, t \rangle \subset \Gamma(X, L^n \otimes M)$$ spanned by $s$ and $t$. We then must show that if $Z_i = \{w \in W\;|\;w(q_i) = 0\}$, then $\bigcup Z_i \subseteq W$ is strict. For this, it suffices to show that each $Z_i \subseteq W$ is strict. But then, this is clear since $s \in W \setminus Z_1$ and $t \in W \setminus Z_i$ for $i = 2, \dots, m$.
I want to remark that if the above seems rough and dirty, that's because it is. There is a more natural proof using cohomology that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ and $Z \subset X$ is a closed subscheme, then for $n >> 0$, there is a global section of $\mathcal{F} \otimes L^n$ which doesn't vanish along $Z$.
Using Serre's cohomological characterization of ampleness (cf. section 18.8 in Vakil's notes), there is a short exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow \Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n \otimes I_Z) \longrightarrow \Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n) \longrightarrow\Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n\otimes \mathcal{O}_Z) \longrightarrow 0. $$ But then, $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n\otimes \mathcal{O}_Z) \neq 0$, as it is a nonzero sheaf generated by global sections, so $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n \otimes I_Z) \subset \Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} \otimes L^n)$ is a strict vector subspace, as required.
